# Don't see apex data

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template, template, track

I have such code:

JS

```
    @track messageBody;

    @wire(getDataFromController) 
    emailTemplate ({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.messageBody = data[0].Body; //EmailTemplate Object Body field value
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    };

    get body(){
        return this.messageBody;
    };

    handleEmailTextChange(event){
        this.messageBody = event.target.value;
     };
```

HTML

```
            <template if:true={emailTemplate.data}>
                <lightning-textarea name="emailBody" label="Email Body" value={body} onchange={handleEmailTextChange}></lightning-textarea>
            </template>
```

When I click my quick action, I see all fields except this part. I suppose that is why if:true={emailTemplate.data}. But in debug mode I see my data.

[image]

What I made wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused with params.

`if:true` in LWC only expects value in `true` and `false`.
And `emailTemplate` wired method `error` and `data` is not something which should be referred like you are referring.

So your `<template if:true={emailTemplate.data}>` should change to :

`<template if:true={valueAvailable}>`

---

```
valueAvailable = false;

@wire(getDataFromController) 
emailTemplate ({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.messageBody = data[0].Body; //EmailTemplate Object Body field value
        this.error = undefined;
        this.valueAvailable = true;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.record = undefined;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Now everything is great!